# return responseEntity breaks flow

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, httpresponse, stax

I am using a StAX parser, that uses the `XMLStreamReader` interface. `XMLSteamReader`.`next` throws the `XMLStreamException`.

When I return and break the flow, using a ResponseEntity instance

Ex:

```
catch (IOException | XMLStreamException e) {
   message = e.getMessage();
   log.debug(message);
   return new ResponseEntity<String>(message, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}
```

The message I get:

```
[DEBUG] test.rng (No such file or directory)
```

When I don't return,

I get:

```
[DEBUG] test.rng (No such file or directory)
[DEBUG] "fservice/.../1.2.3/1/test.rng.xml" (Line 16): The end-tag for element type "elem" must end with a '>' delimiter.
```

Now, I need to display the second message too, as it is more descriptive. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

The main difference between the two cases is that you `return` in the first, and fall through in the second.

Notice that the errors are actually different: the first is saying that a file can't be found:

> ```
> [DEBUG] test.rng (No such file or directory)
> ```

The second is saying that an XML file is malformed (and notably an *end tag*, meaning that the start tag was found, so the file was found):

> ```
> "fservice/.../1.2.3/1/test.rng.xml" (Line 16): The end-tag for element type "elem" must end with a '>' delimiter.
> ```

So the second case is actually a completely different problem, which you don't see in the first case because of the return breaking the control flow.

Comment: but, I checked and it is the same problem that's being addressed? Why two different debug messages? –

Comment: "Why two different debug messages?" No idea. It's not actually clear why the first message is what it is - you've not shown what `DEBUG.message` is.

Comment: So i am guessing that I must not return , in order to get the same message? But isn't that not correct?